# Unit test with android Dagger 2 and Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-2, robolectric

I am doing a unit test with android `dagger2` and `roboletric`，but the objects I inject are `null`. Here the code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Inject
    MemberService memberService;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Application application = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
        DaggerConfigComponent.builder().configModule(new ConfigModule(application))//provide retrofit okhttpclient
                .serviceModule(new ServiceModule())//provide Memberservice
                .build().inject(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
      //user memberservice, but it is null
    }
}
```

*configComponent* includes `ConfigModule` and `ServiceModule`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ConfigModule.class, ServiceModule.class})
public interface ConfigComponent {

    void inject(Object o);

}
```

*ConfigModule*

```
@Module(includes = {DaoSessionModule.class, ServiceModule.class})
public class ConfigModule {

    private Application application;

    public ConfigModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Application provideApplication() {
        return this.application;
    }
 @Singleton
    @Provides
    public OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache, HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
        builder.cache(cache);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            builder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            builder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            builder.writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```

*ServiceModule* provide the `MemberService`

```
@Module
public class ServiceModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public MemberService provideMemberService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(MemberService.class);
    }

}
```

It's my code, hope you can give me some help.
Maybe I used the unit in the wrong way?

Comment: Add the following method to your ConfigComponent : void inject(ExampleUnitTest eut);

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I tried, it didn't work.
Because the ConfigComponent in src/main/java  can't access ExampleUnitTest class in  src/test/java(java unit test directory). So I just write inject(Object obj).
And I tried new a TestConfigComponent in src/test/java(java unit dir), but no DaggerTestConfigComponent generated.

Comment: On your src/test/java, create a component that extends ConfigComponent and injects ExampleUnitTest.

Comment: @Luis if I create a TestConfigComponent in src/test/java, there's no DaggerTestConfigComponent in build dir.(it seems only files in app module can be generated at compile period) so, can not inject